# How to switch between fragments using buttons

Tags: java, android

Fragment 1:

```
public class homePage extends Fragment {


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private View view;

public homePage() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
    Button btnRegister = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loginView();
        }
    });
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerView();
        }
    });
    return view;
}


public static homePage newInstance() {
    homePage fragment = new homePage();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    return fragment;
}


public void registerView(){}
public void loginView(){}


public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

}
}
```

Acitivty :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homePage homepage = new homePage();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, homepage)
                    .commit();
        }
    }




 }
```

My fragment1 has two buttons with the id's "login" and "register". Whenever login is clicked, I want to go to my fragment_login.xml, and when register is clicked I want to go to my fragment_register.xml. Should I create these functions in my activity or in my fragment? And how should I do this? I'm fairly new to android and I'm trying to learn these basic things atm. Thanks for the help :(

Login context: "com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.login"
Register context: "com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.register"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a communication between `Fragment` objects via an `Interface`.

The Activity that make the switch between your fragments needs to implement that `Interface`.

So, in your case your classes must be defined as follows. This is your `Interface`, it helps you to tell your activity that a button has been clicked from within your `Fragment`:

```
public interface HomeClickListener {
    void onLoginClick();
    void onRegisterClick();
}
```

Your Activity needs to implement the above interface in order to be notified when a button has been clicked:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements HomeClickListener {

    void onLoginClick() {
        // Your activity code to replace your current Fragment with your Login fragment
    }

    void onRegisterClick() {
        // Your activity code to replace your current Fragment with your Register fragment
    }

}
```

Your fragment is hosted by an Activity, so you need to have a reference to it and notify it via an `Interface`:

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    final HomeClickListener homeClickListener

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            homeClickListener = (homeClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
        Button btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        Button btnRegister = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.register);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                homeClickListener.onLoginClick();
            }
        });
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                homeClickListener.onRegisterClick();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement).